# WPF combobox default hover color on togglebutton

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a combobox and it's like a simple bar without the arrow.  Almost possible to make all sort of color changes except that I can't figure out how to change the default blue color when hovering on the combobox itself. Your help is greatly appreciated.

What's annoying also is the portion in the styling that seems to be where my answer lies, but even commenting it all out did not cause any issue in building the comboBox, so I wonder if I have to override something to make this happen. It's the portion that is termed "ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate"

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Resources/#AGENCYR" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="34"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="387"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton ClickMode="Press" Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="False"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter
        Margin="3,3,23,3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Name="ContentSite"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
        Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
        IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    <TextBox
        Margin="3,3,23,3"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
        Background="Transparent"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Style="{x:Null}"
        IsReadOnly="False"
        Focusable="True"
        xml:space="preserve"
        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                    <Popup
        Placement="Bottom"
        Name="Popup"
        Focusable="False"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}"
        PopupAnimation="Fade">
      <Grid
          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}"
          Name="DropDown"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Border
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
            Name="DropDownBorder"
            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <ScrollViewer
            Margin="4,6,4,6"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <ItemsPresenter
              KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Grid>
    </Popup>
            </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Window.AllowsTransparency" SourceName="Popup" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton
                        Name="ToggleButton"
                        BorderBrush="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Gray"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Release">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="10,3,30,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Popup
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True"
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <Grid
                            Name="DropDown"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border
                            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                            Background="White"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="Black"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border
                  Name="Border"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                  Padding="2,2,2,2">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush1}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#24afb2" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#24afb2" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#24afb2" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate">
    <Border
Name="PART_ContentHost"
Background="Gray"
Focusable="False" />
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate">
    <!--<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
  BorderBrush="Black"
  CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
  BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
  Name="Border"
  Background="WhiteSmoke"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Border
  Margin="1,1,1,1"
  BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
  CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
  BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
  Background="AliceBlue"
  Grid.Column="0" />
        <Path
  Margin="0,0,3,0"
  Data="M0,0L4,4 8,0z"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
  Name="Arrow"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Width="8"
  Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FF8D979E"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#66FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
</ControlTemplate>


<!-- The Actual ComboBox -->
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbNames" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedName}" DisplayMemberPath ="FirstName" Width="454">
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtComboBox" Style="{StaticResource ComboTextBox}" 
               Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmbNames, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
         Text=" Select ..." />
</Grid>
```

Comment: First observation is that you're setting the `Template` property twice with two separate setters in your `ComboBox` `Style`.  Which is the right one?  Also, the first style references a `ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate`, which you did not provide the Xaml for.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the duplicate template you are seeing, I can remove that!

Comment: <Setter Property="Template">

Comment: Looks good now, just set the `ToggleButton` in your second template to use the `ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate` you created.

Comment: Actually that was a bad idea. I had to uncomment and bring the Template back.  So I guess I am using this template.  Which is the other template I am using - I wonder.

Comment: I think I lost you Mike where the solution is, I tried commenting out what I think is a duplicate template and it seems that wont work.  Somehow I need everything that I show you above.  I still get the blue default hover styling - though.

Answer (score 1):

I've done my best to figure out what you're trying to accomplish here, and I made some tweaks that should at least get you to a reasonable starting point.  I had to improve with the colors since you left out some of the brush resources you were referencing ;).

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBrush1"
                 Color="Magenta" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush"
                 Color="Gray" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="Gray" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush"
                 Color="Gray" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush"
                 Color="Black" />

<DrawingBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush">
  <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                     Geometry="M 0,0 L 4,4 L 8,0 Z" />
  </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox"
                 x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate">
  <Border Name="PART_ContentHost"
          Background="Gray"
          Focusable="False" />
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton"
                 x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
            Name="Border"
            Background="WhiteSmoke"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Path Margin="0,0,3,0"
          Data="M0,0L4,4 8,0z"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
          Name="Arrow"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Width="8"
          Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
              TargetName="Border"
              Value="DodgerBlue" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
              TargetName="Border"
              Value="WhiteSmoke" />
      <Setter Property="Shape.Fill"
              TargetName="Arrow"
              Value="#FF8D979E" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
             Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
              TargetName="Border"
              Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
      <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush"
              TargetName="Border"
              Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
      <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
              Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
      <Setter Property="Shape.Fill"
              TargetName="Arrow"
              Value="#66FFFFFF" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="Black" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily"
          Value="Resources/#AGENCYR" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize"
          Value="16" />
  <Setter Property="FontWeight"
          Value="Normal" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
          Value="Left" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
          Value="Top" />
  <Setter Property="Cursor"
          Value="Arrow" />
  <Setter Property="Height"
          Value="34" />
  <Setter Property="Width"
          Value="387" />
  <Setter Property="MinWidth"
          Value="50" />
  <Setter Property="MinHeight"
          Value="32" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Grid>
          <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                        BorderBrush="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Gray"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Release"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}" />
          <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="10,3,30,3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
          <Popup Name="Popup"
                 Placement="Bottom"
                 IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                 AllowsTransparency="True"
                 Focusable="False"
                 PopupAnimation="Fade">
            <Grid Name="DropDown"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
              <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                      Background="White"
                      BorderThickness="1"
                      BorderBrush="Black" />
              <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
          </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="95" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
                   Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="CornerRadius"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="Margin"
                    Value="0,2,0,0" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                    Value="false" />
            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="Black" />
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Border Name="Border"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Padding="2,2,2,2">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
                    TargetName="Border"
                    Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush1}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
  </Style.Resources>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="#24afb2" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="#24afb2" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsFocused"
                   Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                   Value="False" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="#24afb2" />
    </MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                   Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                   Value="False" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="Black" />
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The style doesn't define a template for editable `ComboBox` instances, which I think may have been what your *other* template was trying to do.  Perhaps you can extract it to a separate template, which you can set via a `Style` setter when `IsEditable` is `True`.

Comment: I am trying to read through what makes it work in your XAML and not mines. Is this the code that does the trick, I am plugging it in my XAML and it does not work                                           <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
              TargetName="Border"
              Value="DodgerBlue" />

Comment: Seems like I need that another template to override the arrow and not show it. And adding that template is the one that causes the default hover blue behavior back, even in your XAML

Answer (score 0):

Mike, I took your template and embedded it with mine using the textbox, however I got the arrow back in the comboBox which I really wanted to avoid.  But the good thing was that I removed the textbox from inside the combobox template and was able to remove that another template.... (it's all shown as commented)

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Resources/#AGENCYR" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA2C3C4" />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF3CEFF4" />-->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />-->
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox"
             x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate">
        <Border Name="PART_ContentHost"
      Background="Gray"
      Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton"
             x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
        CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
        BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
        Name="Border"
        Background="Gray"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

            <Path Margin="0,0,3,0"
      Data="M0,0L4,4 8,0z"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
      Name="Arrow"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Width="8"
      Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver"
         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
          TargetName="Border"
          Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"
         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
          TargetName="Border"
          Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill"
          TargetName="Arrow"
          Value="#FF8D979E" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
          TargetName="Border"
          Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush"
          TargetName="Border"
          Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
          Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill"
          TargetName="Arrow"
          Value="#66FFFFFF" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
      Value="#FF3CEFF4" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
      Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
      Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
      Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
      Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
      Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
      Value="Resources/#AGENCYR" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
      Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
      Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
      Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
      Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor"
      Value="Arrow" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
      Value="34" />
        <Setter Property="Width"
      Value="387" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth"
      Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight"
      Value="32" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                    BorderBrush="Gray"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Focusable="false"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ClickMode="Release"
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="10,3,30,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <!-- REMOVED THIS ONE TOO <TextBox
            Margin="3,3,23,3"
            Visibility="Hidden"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
            Background="Transparent"
            VerticalAlignment="Left"
            Style="{x:Null}"
            IsReadOnly="False"
            Focusable="True"
            xml:space="preserve"
            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate}"/>-->
                        <Popup Name="Popup"

             Placement="Bottom"
             IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
             AllowsTransparency="True"
             Focusable="False"
             PopupAnimation="Fade">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border Name="DropDownBorder"
                  Background="White"
                  BorderThickness="1"
                  BorderBrush="Black" />
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems"
               Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
               Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
               Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency"
               Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                Property="CornerRadius"
                Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                Property="Margin"
                Value="0,2,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
               Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="false" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite"
                Property="Visibility"
                Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!-- FINALLY REMOVED THIS ONE <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton
                            Name="ToggleButton"
                            BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="Gray"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ClickMode="Release">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ContentSite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="10,3,30,3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Popup
                            Name="Popup"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            AllowsTransparency="True"
                            Focusable="False"
                            PopupAnimation="Fade">
                            <Grid
                                Name="DropDown"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="White"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="Black"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>-->
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
      Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border Name="Border"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Padding="2,2,2,2">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted"
               Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
                TargetName="Border"
                Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush1}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
               Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#24afb2" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#24afb2" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsFocused"
               Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
               Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#24afb2" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
               Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
               Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="Black" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This now works by setting the ToogleButton in ControlTemplate for both the trigger as:

```
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border"  Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
```

And the combobox being used:

```
            <!-- The Actual ComboBox -->
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbNames" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedName}" DisplayMemberPath ="FirstName" Width="454">
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtComboBox" Style="{StaticResource ComboTextBox}" 
                           Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmbNames, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
                     Text=" Select ..." />
            </Grid>
```

Hopefully someone can look at this temp solution and offer me the solution on how to get rid of the arrow on the combobox.